# How to add Alert Action in Table view Cell & .xib (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertaction

I'm super beginner in swift world.

I use UITableView in Main.Storyboard, and in .xib file, I use UITableViewCell

Here is some code in ViewController.swift, related with UITableView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var friendsTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    friendsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contacts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let entry = contacts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.configureWithContactEntry(entry)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

Here is the code in TableViewCell.swift, related with  TableViewCell.xib.

```
@IBOutlet weak var contactNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contactPhoneLabel: UILabel!

    override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func configureWithContactEntry(_ contact: ContactEntry) {
    contactNameLabel.text = contact.name
    contactPhoneLabel.text = contact.phone ?? ""

}
```

And, in TableViewCell.xib I use UITableViewCell, 2 Labels.

In this condition,
How can i add AlertAction when I press one of my table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your alertViewController to your TableViewController not the cell itself. 
But as you want the alert view to show once the user touches a cell just implement tableViewDidselectRow and present your alertView from there

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is an Alert", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

now by touching a cell it will present an alert